# Textmining in R using qunateda package, rpart

Tags: nlp, text-mining, rpart, quanteda

I just joined stackoverflow to find solution for this error. After running the following code, R throws error (see below). Pls help me how to solve this. I am new to text mining.

```
rpart.cv.1 <- train(Include ~ ., data = x, method = "rpart", trControl = cv.cntrl, tuneLength = 10).
```

> Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) :    duplicated name
>   'document' in data frame using '.'

Comment: You could converta  DFM to a regular sparse matrix by `as(x, "dgCMatrix")` to avoid DFM's constraints, such as uniqueness of document names.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As you recommended, I converted the DFM to regular sparse matrix and then to DF. The error persisted.

Comment: ```names(my_dataframe)=make.names(names(my_dataframe), unique=TRUE) 
```
solved the error. But, anothe one merges: memory issue. "Cannot allocate a vector size of xGB. "